# 802.3at PoE power splitter design - how to pass the actual Ethernet signal along

Tags: poe

I'm researching the design of a PoE splitter. I understand the actual 802.3at portion of things, and have some confidence in being able to get the 48 VDC out (TPS2378).

The question I have is... I've got the center tapped 1:1 transformers on the incoming pairs. That's fine. But what do I do with the secondaries of the transformers such that I can just connect up to an RJ45 intended to be the jack for the target device?

Is it just simply wiring the secondaries to the output jack?

Comment: Have you got centre taps on incoming and outgoing magnetics?

Comment: Yes. That's required to pull the power off.

Comment: Wait.  "Outgoing magnetics"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This schematic](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP1081SPCGEVB_SCHEMATIC.PDF) appears to answer the question: the output of the secondary of the magnetics appears to go directly to the outgoing RJ45 jack.

Comment: If that's solved it don't forget to mark your answer as accepted, otherwise it'll keep getting bumped as unanswered.

Comment: Since I answered my own question, there was a waiting period.